# Fitting points to a polynomial, except by minimaxing instead of least squares

Tags: polynomials, optimization

I have a bunch of (x, y) points.

I know algorithms to fit them to a polynomial, but they optimize the sum of squares of the points' deviations from the curve.

Instead, I need to minimize the maximum absolute value of points' deviation.

Consider:

1. If I needed to draw a horizontal line which would be optimal in a least-squares sense, I would calculate the Expected value across my points. Since, instead of that, I need it to be optimal in minimax sense, I would instead find max and min values across my points and use their average.
2. If I needed to draw a line at an angle which would be optimal in a least-squares sense, I would use

[image]

Since, instead of that, I need it to be optimal in minimax sense, I would instead ??? ???? ??.

Comment: Are we using a line or a polynomial? If it's the latter, is there a constraint for the maximum degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @VTand my original desire was to get a generic algorithm for any degree (starting with the line a.k.a. first degree polynomial), akin to how we divide the Vandermonde matrix when searching for the least square solution (in that case we can choose whatever matrix size we want). But in case that's too non-trivial I guess I'll settle for 2nd degree, or maybe even a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this minimax ($L_\infty$) polynomial regression problem via linear programming.  See [Curve Fitting: Fitting a Curve to a Set of Data Points](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_021/ormpex/ormpex_ex11_toc.htm), which demonstrates both $L_\infty$ and $L_1$.

Comment: Thanks, but the link you've posted is just a programming manual for how to solve this problem with a math suite. The algorithm _itself_ is hidden inside the suite and not explained there (or at least I couldn't find it). This does not help much.

Comment: The "Mathematical Programming Formulation" section describes the LP formulation, which you can solve with any LP solver.  The idea is that you don't need to implement a specialized algorithm when you can use LP.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the answer I needed is "go learn what Linear Programming is, then pick a solver according to your taste, then use it". Fair enough, have a green tick.